# What does ls -l | wc do?

Tags: command-line, wc

I cannot figure out what this command does. It produces 3 numbers in my terminal but with no explanation of what those numbers are. I understand `ls -l` lists all files in log list format and `wc` is word count but those numbers don't seem to match anything.

Any help?

Comment: `man wc` would tell you what those numbers are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever you don't understand a command, read its manual. In this case, `man wc` would show you that:

```
DESCRIPTION
   Print newline, word, and byte counts for each FILE, and a total line if
   more than one FILE is specified. [...] A  word  is a non-zero-length
   sequence of characters delimited by white space.
```

So, the three numbers are i) the number of lines; ii) the number of words; and iii) the number of bytes. Therefore, if I run it in this directory:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct 19 14:29 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct 19 14:29 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct 19 14:29 file3
```

It will return:

```
$ ls -l | wc
    4      29     152
```

That's because, as you can see above, there are **4** lines of output, which contain **29** "words" (a word is defined by whitespace) and a total of **152** bytes (note that this includes the newline (`\n`) character at the end of each line).

For a simpler example, try:

```
$ echo "foo" | wc  
    1    1     4
```

The command `echo "foo"` actually prints `foo\n` (the `\n` is the newline character), so that's one line, one word and 4 bytes.

Beware that the third field is the number of bytes, not characters. This particularly important in locales where characters can be made of several bytes like when using UTF-8 (tends to be the norm nowadays).

```
$ echo fée | wc
    1    1    5
```

In UTF-8, the é character is made of two bytes. You can use the `-m` option to get the number of characters (`m` is for *multibyte characters*).

```
$ echo fée | wc -m
4
```